# Delete all resources via OC CLI with name contain some words

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am looking for a command to delete all resources in openshift, with name contain some words.

I found this but NOT specific to mine. [POD delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068873/delete-all-pods-when-starts-for-a-word-uncomplete-name-of-the-pod)

I tried below

```
oc get all -- selector | awk '/^<some word>/{system("oc delete all --selector " $1)}'
```

it gives below error though. Other thing search should be any part of the name.(not just beginning)

```
error: you must specify only one resource
```

Further I noticed below command won't delete `configmap`

```
oc delete all --selector app=<app_name> -o name
```

Comment: Hi, I would try with `oc get all  -oname | grep -i blaah | xargs oc delete`

Comment: @SureshVishnoi This work perfectly, only thing is it doesn't delete the config map. Is that `oc delete` restriction?

Comment: I think Configmap and Secrets are not part of the `all` groups.

Comment: If you wanna understand further why all does not show all of the resources, check out here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in above comment sections.

`oc get all -oname | grep -i “blaah" | xargs oc delete` will delete most of the namespaced resources such as pod,replicaset,deployment,service.  However, ConfigMap ,Secret and CRDs won’t be deleted as they do not belong to `all` Category.

Comment: Annoying but simple way to extend the set of resources is using commas:  
`oc get all,configmap,pvc -oname`

Comment: yea, there must be a reason for not including these resources in the `all` category.